# Who were the two daughters of Muhammad who died in the month of Ramadan?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Two daughters of Muhammad (SAW) died in the month of Ramadan. I want to know which two daughters were they?

Answer (score 0):

Hazrat Ruqayya (R.A) Died during the battle of Badr. She was burried just before the Prophet (SAW) and his companions returned from Badr. Badr was fought on 17th of Ramazan.

Hazrat Fatima (R.A) died about six months after the death of Mohammad (SAW) on 3rd of Ramazan 11 A.H.

Comment: Wikipedia lists [Fatima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatimah) as dying 3 [Jumada al-Thani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumada_al-Thani), not during Ramadan (although it's listed as "disputed").  Is there some evidence to contradict this?